# Cannot reopen jquery ui dialog after closing it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a link on my website which opens a html content from a different webpage in a jquery ui dialog:

```
var $otherDialogContainer = $('#other-dialog');

$('a.link').click(function() {
    $otherDialogContainer.load('/controller/action', function() {
        $otherDialogContainer.dialog({
        title: 'Hello',
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            position: 'middle',
            resizable: false
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

In the html that's opened in the dialog there is a button which closes the dialog like this:

```
$('.closeDialog').click(function() {
        window.parent.$(".ui-dialog").remove();
    });
```

The problem is, I cannot reopen the dialog after I close it with that button. If I close the dialog by clicking the 'x' icon in the top right corner, I can reopen it without a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.remove() removes the dialog from the DOM so there is no longer a dialog to open :)

You should use

```
$otherDialogContainer.dialog('close');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, the problem is that won't close the dialog (it's html page from external source).

Comment: Isnt the content just loaded via ajax into a div in your DOM and then converted to a dialog on the success event? Surely it would still work? Sorry If I've misunderstood!!

Comment: Yes. But the button for closing the dialog is inside the dialog. So it's inside the HTML from external source. $otherDialogContainer.dialog('close'); won't work from inside the dialog.

Comment: Add another DIV inside the dialog and do your ajax load into that? Then have the close button outside the loaded DIV but still inside the Dialog?

Comment: @Chris Ok the problem was I was not using the jquery ui dialog "buttons" option. I was just putting buttons there manually with HTML. When I used jquery ui buttons it works.